# Devenir (un) matin (comme tous les autres)

Tags: articles, absence-d-article

> C’est un soir ordinaire qui se transforme nonchalamment en nuit, nuit
> qui à son tour deviendra **un** matin comme tous les autres. (1)

Cette phrase est correcte.

> C’est un soir ordinaire qui se transforme nonchalamment en nuit, nuit
> qui à son tour deviendra matin. (2)
>
> C’est un soir ordinaire qui se transforme nonchalamment en nuit, nuit
> qui à son tour deviendra **un** matin. (3)

Ces phrases sont aussi correctes. Mais est-ce que la phrase (2) est plus belle que la phrase (3) ?

Est-il possible d'omettre l'article dans la première phrase ***deviendra matin** comme tous les autres* ?

Answer (score 1):

Oui, il est possible de s'affranchir de l'article dans un texte littéraire mais choisir quelle phrase est la plus belle est subjectif, *opinion based*...

> *Alors, tandis que déjà l'aurore devient matin, à perte de vue, la grande boucherie commence.*
> Joseph Delteil, *Perpignan*, 1927.